# Style of Book is 17cmX24cm

Tags: paper-size

I want to make my book with size 17cmX24cm but I don't know how to set it into my tex?

Comment: Probably easy to do. What is 'my tex' though? Does your document contain a line `\documentclass` near the top of the file or `\stoptext` or `\bye` near the bottom of the file?

Answer (score 2):

If LaTeX is used, package [`geometry`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) helps:

```
\usepackage[
  paperwidth=17cm,
  paperheight=24cm,
  % other options
]{geometry}
```

Or package `typearea` of KOMA-Script:

```
\usepackage[
  paper=24cm:17cm, % (height and width are interchanged up to version 3.01a)
]{typearea}
```